# LocomotiveCMS: Page not pushable

Tags: locomotivecms

I have already asked this on the [LCMS Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/locomotivecms/tCqk5RvA3Ps), but the post got 3 views in a week and I can't continue my project with an entire page missing...

I have been getting an error when trying to push a specific page on wagon 1.5.4 on locomotivehosting and on my own hosting server. Everything works fine on the local wagon serve.

> Warning: NOT all the pages were pushed.
>   Check that the pages inheritance was done right OR that you translated all your pages.

The strange thing is that it works on *some* pages that are almost identical (see below). My original problem was with the "elektronik-entwicklung" page.

[Image: some pages were uploaded, but not all.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEyrX.png)

What I have tried:

- deleted and re-pushed entire website
- pushed pages with different slugs and same content, which only worked partially

I tried updating a lot of almost identical pages just with varying names and slugs, only to find out that there was no system behind the choice of which pages got uploaded (e.g. "l-entwicklung.liquid" got pushed, but "a-entwicklung.liquid" didn't get pushed; cf. image on Google Group post).

The files I created to test have the same content, just the corresponding slugs are different. E.g.:

```
---
title: Elektronik
slug: elektronik-entwicklung
listed: true
published: true
---

{% extends engineering/engineering-subpage %}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of pain, I finally decided to upgrade the whole thing to locomotivecms 3.0 and wagon 2.0.
This solved the problem.